# Does anyone know the correct way to verify the color temperature of a given light source in a color booth and the equipment needed?

Tags: visible-light

ie. spectroradiometer on the floor (constant distance) of the booth directly measuring the "observed" color temp emitted directly from the light source? is it more acurate to measure the light absorbed on a white piece of paper?

Comment: https://www.rp-photonics.com/color_temperature.html#Measurement%20of%20Color%20Temperatures

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is probably an ASTM specification of you want to go that far

Comment: I want to understand reliable means  to verify the actual color temp of a light sourcre in a color booth.  Also, it seems that I mis-typed.  Should have said , "is it more acurate to measure the light   "reflected"   off a white piece of paper? BTW, there is not a pertinent ASTM.